# How to get checkbox value in angularjs?

Tags: arrays, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, angularjs-filter, angular-routing

I have a 10(or n)checkbox in my ng-view. Now I would like to ask here that 
What is the most efficient or simple way to check if checkbox is checked and if checked get the value of checkbox.

```html
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="album in albums">
   <input type="checkbox" ng-model="folder.Selected" value={{album.name}} />
   </li>
  </ul>
```

I have **ng-controller(getAlbumsCtrl)**, in that I have an array in which I want to push all the checkedbox albums names into **albumNameArray**

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can loop over the array to find out which is selected and push into the name array.

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="album in albums">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="album.selected" value={{album.name}} />
  </li>
</ul>

$scope.save = function(){
  $scope.albumNameArray = [];
  angular.forEach($scope.albums, function(album){
    if (!!album.selected) $scope.albumNameArray.push(album.name);
  })
}

// alternatively you can use Array.prototype.filter on newer browsers (IE 9+)
$scope.save = function(){
  $scope.albumNameArray = $scope.albums.filter(function(album){
    return album.selected;
  });
}
```

[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/buxixixisa/1/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: I think if (!!album.selected) should be simple 
'if (album.selected) 
{
$scope.albumNameArray.push(album.name);'
}
But when I doing so.. I am getting (album.selected) = undefined. However, just for checking purpose I did value = {{album.selected}} it is true..but when in controller it is giving me undefined error..

Comment: This is what I am doing 
JavaScript:-
  angular.forEach($scope.albums, function (album) {

            if (album.selected)
            {
                $scope.albumNames.push(album.name);
           }
        });
HTML :-

<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-inline" ng-model="album.selected" value="{{album.name}}" /> 

I am getting album.selected = undefined.

Comment: sorry I didn't see the checkbox value. Normally I don't put value when I use checkbox, just using ng-model. If value has an effect on the model, can you check whether the model is already the name itself instead of the object?

Comment: I have 2 configurations in my routeConfig.. one is

$routeProvider.
      when('/albums', {
          templateUrl: 'xyz.html',
          controller: 'getAlbumsCtrl'
      })
        .when('/Album/:AlbumName', {
            templateUrl: 'xyz.html',
            controller: 'getAlbums12Ctrl'
        })

in getAlbums12Ctrl(), I am colllecting AlbumName is $routeParams, but what I need is whatever follows Album/* please collect it in AlbumName($routeParams)

like this 
** /albums/bollywood >>(AlbumName = "bollywood")**
**/albums/bollywood/old >> (AlbumName = "bollywood/old)"
/albums/*

Comment: I might not be knowledgeable enough on routes to answer this question, you can open a new one so others that know more about this may answer.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vppravi93/crq3mLt2/),i have used the object whose key is the album name

`<input type="checkbox" ng-model="folder[album.name]" value={{album.name}}/>`

controller:

```
function ctrl($scope){
$scope.albums = [{name:'a1'},{name:'a2'},{name:'a3'}];
$scope.folder = {};
$scope.albumNameArray = [];
$scope.getAllSelected = function(){          
    angular.forEach($scope.folder,function(key,value){
        if(key)
            $scope.albumNameArray.push(value)
    });
}}
```

Comment: hi @praveen can you answer this question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42689519/x-editable-checkbox-in-meanstack-angularjs

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use angular filter here, also your `ng-model` should be `album.Selected` instead of `folder.Selected`

**Html**

```
{{(albums | filter : { Selected: true }: true)}}
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.albumNameArray = $filter('filter')($scope.albums, { Selected: true }, true);
```

> Before using it in controller don't forget to add `$filter` in your
>   controller

Comment: imp for me... 
$scope.save = function() { }

$scope.read = function() {}

suppose I want to call save function from read..because when I am doing I get save() not defined..

I am doing in this way

$scope.read = function()
{
save();
}

Comment: @Chetan as both method in scope then it should be `$scope.read = function() { $scope.save(); } `

Comment: I have 2 configurations in my routeConfig.. one is

$routeProvider.
      when('/albums', {
          templateUrl: 'xyz.html',
          controller: 'getAlbumsCtrl'
      })
        .when('/Album/:AlbumName', {
            templateUrl: 'xyz.html',
            controller: 'getAlbums12Ctrl'
        })

in getAlbums12Ctrl(), I am colllecting AlbumName is $routeParams, but what I need is whatever follows Album/* please collect it in AlbumName($routeParams)
@Pankaj
like this 
** /albums/bollywood >>(AlbumName = "bollywood")**
**/albums/bollywood/old >> (AlbumName = "bollywood/old)"
/albums/*

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the value printed. 
You can use like :

```
input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkboxModel.value2" ng-true-value="'YES'" ng-false-value="'NO'"
```