# Get true or false for list of checkboxes when clicked button in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When I click the "APPLY" button, I need to get all the checked values of the checkboxes.

I am new to AngularJs. I have a list of checkboxes and according to the checkboxes condition I have to select and deselect the table columns, i.e the checkboxes are the actual columns.

**HTML**

```
<li ng-repeat="col in columns">
  <span class="inputH">
    <input type="checkbox" value="col.name" ng-if="col.default === true" checked  ng-model="chk[col.name]" id="{{col.name}}">
    <input type="checkbox" value="col.name" ng-if="col.default === false"  ng-model="chk[col.name]" id="{{col.name}}">
  </span>
  <span class="textH">{{col.name}}</span>
</li>
<li>
  <button class="btn-default" ng-click="onCustomizationApply()">Apply</button>
  <button class="btn-default" ng-click="onCustomization()">Cancel</button>
 </li>
```

If you notice, `onCustomizationApply()`, on this I need to get all checkboxes which are checked

Comment: Can you provide a JSFiddle or Plnkr?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get checkbox value in angularjs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31090788/how-to-get-checkbox-value-in-angularjs)

Answer (score 0):

try this
give common class to all checkbox

```
<li ng-repeat="col in columns">
<span class="inputH">
<input class="mychkbox"type="checkbox" value="col.name" ng-if="col.default === true" ng-model="chk[col.name]" id="{{col.name}}">
<input class="mychkbox" type="checkbox" value="col.name" ng-if="col.default === false"  ng- model="chk[col.name]" id="{{col.name}}">
</span>
<span class="textH">{{col.name}}</span>
</li>
<li>
<button class="btn-default" ng-click="onCustomizationApply()">Apply</button>
<button class="btn-default" ng-click="onCustomization()">Cancel</button>
</li>
```

in function
    onCustomizationApply()

```
angular.forEach($(".gridCheck"),function(val,index){

if(val.checked){
//here we will get those fields which are checked and we can perform   operation
}
})
```

Answer (score 0):

So I modified your code a bit and made a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/5415/

HTML:

```
<li ng-repeat="col in columns">
    <span class="inputH">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-value="col.default" value="col.name" ng-model="chk[col.name]" id="{{col.name}}">
  </span>
    <span class="textH">{{col.name}}</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button class="btn-default" ng-click="onCustomizationApply()">Apply</button>
    <button class="btn-default" ng-click="onCustomization()">Cancel</button>
  </li>
```

Angular:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.columns = [{
    name: 'col1',
    default: true
  }, {
    name: 'col2',
    default: true
  }, {
    name: 'col3',
    default: true
  }];

  $scope.chk = {};

  $scope.onCustomizationApply = function() {
    console.log($scope.chk);
  };
}
```

Comment: why did you removed another checkbox, basically the value of selected checkbox will get saved in a cookie. and on load I am going to read it, depending I will check or uncheck the checkbox

Comment: Ah ok, can you add this extra info in the OP?

Answer (score 0):

if you change your code (ng-model) from

```
<input type="checkbox" value="col.name" ng-if="col.default === true" checked  ng-model="chk[col.name]" id="{{col.name}}">
```

to

```
<input type="checkbox" value="col.name" ng-if="col.default === true" checked  ng-model="col.colName" id="{{col.name}}">
```

since ng-model is set to {{col.colName}} when you change this value, value of col in columns also changes. Therefore on click event of button you can iterate through columns to see if value it is checked or not.

```
 angular.forEach($scope.columns, function (value, key) {
        if (value.colName == true) {
            //checked
        }
        else {
            //not checked
        }
    });
```