# X editable-checkbox in MEANSTACK angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, x-editable

I am binding the data in a HTML table using ng-repeater now I need to show a checkbox in the table depends upon a db value whether true or false. Values are stored correctly I am not able to display in table please kindly help.

```
<tr dir-paginate="contacts in contactdetail |itemsPerPage:5| filter:search | orderBy:orderByField:reverseSort " ng-class-odd="'odd'">



                                <td id="Ftablerowcolor">

                                    <span contenteditable="true" e-ng-change="applyHighlight($data)" editable-text="contacts.FirstName" e-name="FirstName" e-form="rowform" onaftersave="Fclick(contacts._id,contacts.FirstName)">{{ contacts.FirstName || 'empty' }}
                                    </span>

                                </td>
                                <td ng-click="rowform.$show()" id="Ltablerowcolor">
                                    <span e-ng-change="applyHighlight($data)" editable-text="contacts.LastName" e-name="LastName" e-form="rowform" onaftersave="Lclick(contacts._id,contacts.LastName)">{{ contacts.LastName || 'empty' }}
                                    </span>

                                </td>
                                <td ng-click="rowform.$show()" id="Etablerowcolor">
                                    <span e-ng-change="applyHighlight($data)" editable-text="contacts.Email" e-name="Email" e-form="rowform" onaftersave="Ehkclick(contacts._id,contacts.Email)">{{ contacts.Email || 'empty' }}
                                    </span>


                                </td>
                                <td ng-click="rowform.$show()" id="Ctablerowcolor">

                                    <span e-ng-change="applyHighlight($data)" editable-text="contacts.DisplayName" e-name="DisplayName" e-form="rowform" onaftersave="Dhkclick(contacts._id,contacts.DisplayName)">{{ contacts.DisplayName || 'empty' }}
                                    </span>

                                </td>
                                <td id="Ntablerowcolor"  >

        <span editable-checkbox="contacts.Number" e-name="enabled" e-form="rowform"></span>



                                </td>
                                </tr>
```

Comment: post your ng repeat code.

Comment: Hi @jenny i posted ng-repeat code here iam using dir-paginate for pagination