# How to get checked values from checkbox using Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, json

Am new to angular JS. I have following check box and the data is coming from web service:

```
 <label ng-repeat="r  in MedicalConditions track by $index">
    <input ng-model="ids[$index]" type="checkbox" ng-checked="r.value"> 
       {{r.conditions_name}}
    </label>
```

In console.log value is perfectly right as per my requirements. How to push value to an array i.e., arr[] and stringify it. I tried code like this..

//To fetch Medical Conditions List

```
$scope.parameter = "{}";
$scope.class0 = "{}";
$http.get('http://192.168.1.129:8080/apartment//member/medical/conditions/list').then(function(response) {
    $scope.MedicalConditions = response.data.list;
});

  $scope.$watchCollection('ids', function(newVal) {     
       $scope.parameter.class0 = $scope.ids;
    }); 


$scope.alertdata = function() {
    var parameter = {
        "first_name": $scope.first_name,

        "role": [{
            "role_id": 1,
            "name": "Admin",
            "details": "text"
        }],
        "associated": [{
            "associated_id": 1,
            "associated_name": "Parent",
            "primary_member_id": 1
        }],
        "class0": $scope.ids
    }
    parameter = JSON.stringify(parameter);
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ruzw4Lfb/8/

Comment: @Sinchan $scope.lists[] is assigned in my case data is coming from dynamically.. How to do in my case..

Comment: can you please create a fiddle?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get checkbox value in angularjs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31090788/how-to-get-checkbox-value-in-angularjs)

Comment: You should try binding dynamic Check boxes value using ng-model first . Then other things'll be easier to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<label ng-repeat="r  in MedicalConditions track by $index">
<input ng-model="ids[$index]" type="checkbox" ng-change="valCh(r)"> {{r.conditions_name}}
</label>
```

Controller code will look like this :

```
var postApp = angular.module('EntityApp', []);
postApp.controller('EntityAppCntroller', function($scope, $http, $window, $timeout, $location) {

    //To fetch Medical Conditions List    
        $http.get('http://111.222.444:8080/apartment//member/medical/conditions/list').then(function(response) {
            $scope.MedicalConditions = response.data.list;
        });
        var list = [];
        $scope.valCh = function(value) {
            list.push(value);
            JSON.stringify(list);
        }

        $scope.alertdata = function() {
            var parameter;
            parameter = {
                "parameter": {
                    "first_name": $scope.first_name,
                    "medicalconditions": list
                }
            }
            $http({
                url: 'http://111.222.333:8080/apartment//save/member/details',
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                data: JSON.stringify(parameter)
            }).success(function(data, status) {
                if (data.status == 'success') {
                    alert("User Created");
                    $location.reload();
                } else if (data.status == 'failure') {
                    alert("Some failure please try again later !!!");
                }
            });
        };
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

May be this will help:

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('Controller', function($scope) {
  
  $scope.ids = {};
  $scope.arr = {};
  
  $scope.MedicalConditions = {};
  
  $scope.MedicalConditions[0] = {};
  $scope.MedicalConditions[0].value= true;
  $scope.MedicalConditions[0].conditions_name= 'first value';
  
  $scope.MedicalConditions[1] = {};
  $scope.MedicalConditions[1].value= false;
  $scope.MedicalConditions[1].conditions_name= 'seconde value';
   
    $scope.$watchCollection('ids', function(newVal) {     
       $scope.parameter.class0 = $scope.ids;
    });
    
    
    $scope.parameter = {};
    $scope.parameter.firstname = 'dummy name';
    $scope.parameter.class0 = $scope.ids;
    

  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="Controller">


    <label ng-repeat="r  in MedicalConditions track by $index">
     <input ng-model="ids[$index]" type="checkbox" ng-checked="r.value" > {{ r.conditions_name}}
     </label>
  
  
  <br>
  
  Parameter: {{parameter}}


  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the post. You have assigned values $scope.MedicalConditions[0].conditions_name= 'first value'; like that. But in my case the data is comming dynamically from web service. How to do it in my case.?

Comment: @PrashanthHarish it was just to make the snippet work. you could assign the variable when u get the data via $http service.

Comment: why you are trying to push the value into arr, you could get the value in ids model, as you can see in above working snippet

Comment: TypeError: Cannot set property 'class0' of undefined. Error is comming...

Comment: @PrashanthHarish it may be bacause you didn't initialize the parameter variable. you have to define it as an object for the first time.

Comment: Ok I nitialized.     $scope.parameter = "{}";   $scope.class0 = "{}"; But no apending to class0..

Comment: Its appending NULL value.

Comment: @PrashanthHarish update your code so i can see what you are doing wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142444/discussion-between-prashanth-harish-and-gaurav-srivastava).

Answer (score 1):

Try like below...

```js
var app = angular.module('exApp',[]);

app.controller('ctrl', function($scope){
$scope.ids = [];
$scope.arr = [];
$scope.checkSelected = [];
$scope.MedicalConditions = [{"conditions_name":"xxz","conditions_id":"1"}, {"conditions_name":"yyz","conditions_id":"2"}, {"conditions_name":"zzz","conditions_id":"3"}];
$scope.$watchCollection('ids', function(newVal) {       
  for (var i = 0; i < newVal.length; ++i) {
    console.log(newVal[i]);
    $scope.arr.push(newVal[i]);       
}
});

$scope.checkAllR = function () {
            $scope.checkAll = !$scope.checkAll;

            if ($scope.checkAll) {
                $scope.checkSelected = [];
                angular.forEach($scope.MedicalConditions, function (checkR) {                   
                   
                        checkR.check = $scope.checkAll;
                        $scope.checkSelected.push(checkR);
                   
                });
            }
            else {
               $scope.checkSelected = [];
                angular.forEach($scope.MedicalConditions, function (checkR) {
                    var idx = $scope.checkSelected.indexOf(checkR);
                    checkR.check = $scope.checkAll;
                    $scope.checkSelected.splice(idx, 1);
                });
            }
        };

$scope.addChecked = function (checked) {
            if ($scope.checkSelected == undefined || $scope.checkSelected == null) {
                $scope.checkSelected = [];
            }

            var idx = $scope.checkSelected.indexOf(checked);

            // delete if exists
            if (idx > -1) {
                $scope.checkSelected.splice(idx, 1);
                checked.check = false;
            }
                // add
            else {
                $scope.checkSelected.push(checked);
                checked.check = true;               
            }       
$scope.checkAll = $scope.checkSelected.length == $scope.MedicalConditions.length ? true : false;
        };
var parameter = {
   "first_name": $scope.first_name,
   "middle_name": $scope.middle_name,
   //"class0": /*stringified data i.e., arr[] */ 
};
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="exApp" ng-controller="ctrl">
 Select All : <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="1" ng-checked="checkAll" ng-click="checkAllR()"><br>
<label ng-repeat="r  in MedicalConditions">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" class="check-nolabel" value="1" ng-checked="r.check" ng-click="addChecked(r)"> {{ r.conditions_name}}
 </label><br><br>
 {{checkSelected}}
 </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps.

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <label ng-repeat="r in MedicalConditions track by $index">
    <input ng-model="ids[$index]" 
      ng-init="ids[$index] = r.value"
      type="checkbox"> 
    {{r.condition}}
  </label>
</div>
```

And here is your controller.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.ids = [];

    $scope.MedicalConditions = [{
    _id: 1,
    value: true,
    condition: 'Condition 1'
  }, {
    _id: 2,
    value: false,
    condition: 'Condition 2'
  }, {
    _id: 3,
    value: true,
    condition: 'Condition 3'
  }];
});
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ruzw4Lfb/82/)

Comment: Thanks for your post. I solved by my self for this query..:)